# libpam linking issue ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, pam

I have installed 
libpam0g-dev libpam0g

But when I am linking to libpam I am getting error  undefined reference to `pam_start'
and I am linker flags include -lpam.

Same code is working in Ubuntu 11.

Linking flags

```
-Wl,--start-group  -lssl -lpam -lcrypto  -lnspr4 -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lcurl -lcares -lpthread -lpcrecpp -loauth -ldl -lrt -lz  -Wl,--end-group
```

don't works

but this works

```
-Wl,--start-group  -lssl -lpam -lcrypto  -lnspr4 -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lcurl -lcares -lpthread -lpcrecpp -loauth -ldl -lrt -lz -lpam -Wl,--end-group
```

Comment: Can you provide a small demo program and the exact command you are trying to compile/link it with.

Comment: Ubunto 11.10 and 12.04 use multiarch which means many libraries are installed in different locations. The tools ought to be able to cope with this, but maybe your build system overrides it?

Comment: @ams I updated the problem with more details. Seems like group is not working correctly.

Comment: It does indeed look suspicious! You're certainly not *supposed* to need to repeat libraries within a group. I checked on my system, and `-Wl` passes the options through in the right place. Try running your link with `-v` and see if the linker command looks right to you?